# Haskell - Functors

Tags: haskell, functor

I'm trying to understand how Functors work, so I read about it here: http://learnyouahaskell.com/making-our-own-types-and-typeclasses#the-functor-typeclass

I have a function that takes a map and calculates the sum of the values (which is a list).

```
reduce :: Map String [Int] -> Map String Int
reduce = fmap sum
```

I didn't really understand how the `fmap` worked so I read about it and tried to make my own version. i can't really test it because Map is already defined in the Haskell library.

So is this right?

```
instance Functor (Map k) where  
    fmap f fromList[] = []
    fmap f fromList[(k, v): xs] = (f v) fmap xs
```

Comment: Not directly relevant to your example, but I found this blog post very clear in explaining functors http://adit.io/posts/2013-04-17-functors,_applicatives,_and_monads_in_pictures.html

Comment: "i can't really test it because Map is already defined" - You don't need to declare a `Functor` instance to test your code. Just define your function by itself, and rename it to something that doesn't clash with an existing function (e.g. `fmap'`).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your example is morally on the right track, but there are a few mistakes in it. The most evident is that you can not pattern match on `fromList ...` since `fromList` is not a constructor. The actual constructors are not exported by the `Data.Map` module so we can not pattern match at all -- this is to ensure that you can not access the internal tree representation used in that module and possibly break some invariant.

A better instance could be e.g. (the constraint `Ord k` is required by `Map`, as @gallais mentions)

```
instance Ord k => Functor (Map k) where
   fmap f m = fromList (map modify (toList m))
         where modify (k,v) = (k, fv)
```

this basically turns the whole map into an association list made of key-value pairs, then changes every value applying `f`, and then rebuilds the Map back. More succinctly, it can be written as

```
instance Ord k => Functor (Map k) where
   fmap f = fromList . map (\(k,v) -> (k,f v)) . toList
```

Keep in mind that this is not terribly efficient -- the actual instance in the Map module does not have to pass through an intermediate list.

Finally, note that you can not define your own instance since the Map module already provides one for you. If you really want to experiment with it, you can declare a `newtype`:

```
newtype MyMap k v = MyMap { unMyMap :: Map k v }

instance Functor (MyMap k) where
   fmap f = MyMap . fromList . map (\(k,v) -> (k,f v)) . toList . unMyMap
```

Comment: You probably need an `Ord k` constraint on that `Functor` instance. Also, anecdotically, the definition can be made even more succing given that `((,) k)` is itself a functor. You can write `fromList . fmap (fmap f) . toList`.